# Get n random elements from ArrayList based on condition, and remove them from original list

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Take a list: `List<MyObject> objects = new ArrayList<>();`, where each `MyObject` has a field `String myString;`.

How can I "pop" (retrieve and remove) `n` **random** elements from the list where `myString == "myString"`?

**Edit:**

I have successfully been able to remove a random element from the list, which I can iterate `n` times, but this seems fairly inefficient. Also there is no comparative aspect in the code I have.

```
List<MyObject> objects = new ArrayList<>();
MyObject object = objects.get(Math.random() * objects.size());
objects.remove(object);
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Does it work?

Comment: Which part do you have problems with? Getting random elements of the list? Or checking the condition? Or something else? Or maybe you didn't even try to do it yourself?

Comment: Edited with what I have tried, sorry! Checking the condition (filter) is what I am having problems with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 List<MyObject> filtered = objects.stream()
            .filter(o -> o.getMyString().equals("myString"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

Collections.shuffle(filtered);
List randomList = filtered.subList(0, n);
objects.removeAll(randomList);
```